# Can Brownian Motion be considered a Markov chain?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, brownian-motion, discrete-time

Let's say we have a $1$ dim. Brownian motion, $(B_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)}$. Please note the continuous time.
 How could one prove that $B_t$ is a Markov chain ? Do we define a stochastic matrix using the Gaussian kernel?

I would appreciate a few hints or even a full answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a fixed grid $t_n:=nt_1$, the values $B_n:=B_{t_n}$ are a continuous space Markov Chain. The transition kernel is a Gaussian with variance $t_1$.

Comment: It is a quintessential example of Markov process. So its values along the linear sequence of times $t_n=an$ for $a>0$ becomes a Markov chain.